# Moment .isAfter not returning correctly

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a string that is stored in UTC time.  I am trying to see if this time is after the current UTC time.  I am using momentjs and the isAfter() method returns the incorrect value when there is only 1 hour difference.

The active_time variable happens at 15:00 utc.  The current_time is set to 16:00 utc.  So I think `active_time.isAfter(current_time)` should return `false` but it is returning `true`.  How can I make it return `false`?

jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/Ln1bz1nx/

Code:

```
//String is already in utc time
var active_time = moment('2015-06-04T15:00Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm[Z]');

//Convert current time to moment object with utc time
var current_time = moment( moment('2015-06-04T16:00Z').utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm[Z]') ); 

console.log('active_time =',active_time);
console.log('current_time =',current_time);
console.log( active_time.isAfter(current_time) ); //Why does this return true?
```

Comment: Returns `false` to me: http://jsfiddle.net/Ln1bz1nx/3/

Comment: Weird.  It's always `true` for me.  I'm using a Macbook, I don't know if that could have something to do with it.

Comment: i do not get reliable results from isAfter. If I use .unix() on both moments I can compare, but otherwise if they are in different timezones or come from different sources, it doesn't work reliably.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Even though the first date string is utc, you still need to put the moment into utc mode before you compare. Take a look at the docs here: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/

```js
//String is already in utc time, but still need to put it into utc mode
var active_time = moment.utc('2015-06-04T15:00Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm[Z]');

//Convert current time to moment object with utc time
var current_time = moment.utc('2015-06-04T16:00Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm[Z]');

console.log('active_time =',active_time.format());
console.log('current_time =',current_time.format());
console.log( active_time.isAfter(current_time) );
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/moment/moment/develop/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 8):

If your dates are ISO8601 formatted or timestamp, don't use moment.isAfter. It's 150 times slower than comparing 2 dates objects : http://jsperf.com/momentjs-isafter-performance

```
 var active_time = new Date('2015-06-04T15:00Z');
 var current_time = new Date('2015-06-04T16:00Z');

 console.log('active_time =',active_time);
 console.log('current_time =',current_time);
 console.log( active_time > current_time );
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at the `toDate` method to see what the internal js date is:

```
console.log('active_time =',active_time.toDate());
console.log('current_time =',current_time.toDate());
console.log( active_time.isAfter(current_time) ); //Why does this return true?

active_time = Thu Jun 04 2015 15:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
current_time = Thu Jun 04 2015 09:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
true
```

It's going to depend on what timezone you are in

Comment: Is there a way to check against this?  The response I get has time in the format `YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm[Z]` already in UTC compared to my timezone.

Comment: Use moment.utc() to create the date as a UTC date. See momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/

Answer (score 0):

**It works for me, and it may work for you as well**

```
const dateTime = moment(date).format();
moment(dateTime).isAfter(new Date());
```